# Calculated columns as axis & value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, calculated-columns, m

I have a bunch of calculated DAX columns that I want to show as a visual. If I use a normal bar chart I get the following image, Barchart 1, where because I do not have any fields in the axis field. The titles of each of the calculated columns are what I want the x-axis to be similar to how it is in the funnel chart below.

[image: Barchart 1]

The funnel chart only requires the value field to be filled in and it creates the following image which is kind of what I want but it needs to be vertical similar to the last image.

[image: Barchart 2]

This final image, Barchart 3 is what I want to achieve with my calculated columns but so far I have had no luck in figuring this out. This visual was created using a different file which is irrelevant to the project I am working on now.  I believe that if I could unpivot the calculated columns then it would create the graph I am looking for but I can't figure out how to unpivot columns that are created in DAX. Is there a way to unpivot DAX columns or a visual on the marketplace to accomplish what I am trying to do? Or would I need to create my own custom visual to accomplish this?  Other ideas/thoughts?

[image: Barchart 3]

[Sample data file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SuLqF0qTo0SIlcpxtyImNpprxW56QSW2/view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend creating a calculated table that has `Month` unpivoted so that you only need to put a single series on the bar chart.

For example, you can write a calculated table like this with only 7 columns:

```
CalcTable = 
VAR ThisYear = YEAR ( MAX ( Sheet4[Start] ) )
RETURN
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        CROSSJOIN (
            SELECTCOLUMNS (
                Sheet4,
                "Project", Sheet4[Project],
                "Start", Sheet4[Start],
                "End", Sheet4[End],
                "Cost", Sheet4[Cost]
            ),
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                GENERATESERIES ( 1, 12 ),
                "Month", FORMAT ( DATE ( ThisYear, [Value], 1 ), "MMMM YYYY" )
            )
        ),
        "MonthCost", IF (
            [Value] >= MONTH ( [Start] ) && [Value] <= MONTH ( [End] ),
            DIVIDE ( [Cost], DATEDIFF ( [Start], [End], MONTH ) + 1 ),
            0
        )
    )
```

This table looks like this:

[image: Calculated Table]

And allows you to create a bar chart with `Month` on the axis and sum of `MonthCost` for the values.

[image: Bar Chart]

Comment: Is there an advantage to the way you did it versus the way I did it? I'm figuring out Power BI as I go so I'm curious as to what is the best way to go about this.

Comment: The advantage is that you don't have to define a column per month. Imagine if you had to do this over 10 years.

Comment: Oh that's awesome then. I'm not sure how far I have to go out yet so having it automatically add new columns will be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution to this. It doesn't maintain relationships but it works.

```
Totals Table = 
UNION(
    SUMMARIZE(Sheet4,"Cost",SUM(Sheet4[January 2020]),"Month","January 2020"),
    SUMMARIZE(Sheet4, "Cost", SUM(Sheet4[February 2020]), "Month", "February 2020"),
    SUMMARIZE(Sheet4,"Cost",SUM(Sheet4[March 2020]),"Month","March 2020"),
    SUMMARIZE(Sheet4, "Cost", SUM(Sheet4[April 2020]), "Month", "April 2020"),
    SUMMARIZE(Sheet4,"Cost",SUM(Sheet4[May 2020]),"Month","May 2020"),
    SUMMARIZE(Sheet4, "Cost", SUM(Sheet4[June 2020]), "Month", "June 2020"),
    SUMMARIZE(Sheet4,"Cost",SUM(Sheet4[July 2020]),"Month","July 2020"),
    SUMMARIZE(Sheet4, "Cost", SUM(Sheet4[August 2020]), "Month", "August 2020"),
    SUMMARIZE(Sheet4,"Cost",SUM(Sheet4[September 2020]),"Month","September 2020"),
    SUMMARIZE(Sheet4, "Cost", SUM(Sheet4[October 2020]), "Month", "October 2020"),
    SUMMARIZE(Sheet4,"Cost",SUM(Sheet4[November 2020]),"Month","November 2020"),
    SUMMARIZE(Sheet4, "Cost", SUM(Sheet4[December 2020]), "Month", "December 2020"))
```