# Power BI Calculated table issue

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I have a calculated table in a Power Bi that will not show the DAX code in advance query editor. It is displayed as JSON File exactly like this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60214126/power-query-advanced-editor-json-documentbinary-decompressbinary-fromtext). How can I open and edit this DAX code? I have tried the query editor and the advance query editor and all it displays is the following.

```
= Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45Wcq0oKUrNTc2pVPDJL1fSUTJUitWJVgpLLYIJGIEFIGxjMNsxKb8sFcgzAfNC87Lz8svzgHxTpdhYAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Income Category" = _t, Order = _t])
```

Answer (score 0):

In PowerQuery "Applied Steps" section click on gear icon next to the "Source" line to see the table itself. It may not contain DAX code.